# How to play a DVD on Loki?

Tags: release-loki, videos, audience, video-player

Existing guides specify to install the `libdvdread4` package and then run `sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh` to install DVD decryption support. However on Loki, this results in *sudo: command not found*. Inspecting the `libdvdread4` indeed reveals that the `install-css.sh` script is missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Ubuntu 15.10, `libdvdcss` (the package required for CSS decryption) is installed as part of the `libdvd-pkg` package, with no additional steps required.

```
sudo apt install libdvd-pkg
```

The default *Videos* app in elementary OS is quite buggy, and while the *Play Disc* option appears after installing CSS support, playback fails. A workaround is simply to install *VLC*, which is generally more stable and has better format support.

```
sudo apt install vlc
```

[Source and more info](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs).

Comment: Aferwards I needed to `sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg` to download, compile, and install libdvdcss

Answer (score 0):

On ElementaryOS 5.1 (Hera) all I needed to do (as with many other newer Ubuntu-based distros) to play DVD-s was:

#### Pre-requisites (which are probably already done):

```
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
```

```
sudo apt update
```

#### Required setup:

```
sudo apt install -y gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad
```

#### Usage:

- Insert the DVD.
- Open the **Files** app.
- Click your DVD to load it on the left-hand list of **Devices**.
- Open the **Videos** app.
- Click the <kbd>Play from Disc</kbd> button in the middle.