# DVD Playback: decoding issue after libdvd-pkg installed

Tags: vlc, dvd

Followed instructions on [How to play a DVD on Loki](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/8660/how-to-play-a-dvd-on-loki), but the DVD video would just not play decoded. The sound is ok. But the DVD menus and video content remain encrypted.

#### Running:

- Elementary OS Loki 0.4.1
- 2006 2,1 MacBook Pro 17"
- VLC to read DVDs

#### Tried:

- Uninstalling the Videos app
- Reinstalling `libdvd-pkg`
- Reinstalling `vlc`
- Rebooting

The above didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer will likely not help, but it is worth a shot.

To make movies and music work on Ubuntu run these commands.

> sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras libdvd-pkg
>
> sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg

After that, since VLC is not working, try totem.

> sudo apt-get install totem

reboot the computer, just for good measure, then try to open and play your DVD.

Comment: It does solve the issue completely. Totem has prompted to install two codecs, after first trying to run a DVD, and after rebooting a second time, now playback is fine. But I didn't identify which codecs these were, and VLC still can't play DVD's but that's secondary. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have not had that issue, but I do not use it much for actual DVDs. I will find a fix later this afternoon for you.

Comment: At the top of totem there is a "view" tab. Go ahead and play with the settiing there. Try the settings of "auto" and "zoom in" and it should fix it. Got it working for veggie tales :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I've checked with another DVD it was just one that had it's media cropped compared to the others. Any idea on how to enable the necessary codecs in VLC since the two other players work?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I have not messed with VLC in a long while and don't know how to do things like that in Linux.